# Using python and matplotlib, fill between two lines not giving expected output

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a linear line with associated error.
I calculated values for slope (a) and intercepts (b). In addition, I calculated the error associated with these values. So I drew the line given by the typical formula below.

> y=ax+b

However, in addition to the line, I also want to draw the associated error. I came up with the idea to draw the lines associated with these formulas and color the space between the lines gray.

> y=(a+a_sd)x+(b+b_sd)
>
> y=(a-a_sd)x+(b-b_sd)

Uisng the following piece of code, I am able to color part of the surface between the lines, but not the whole span (see included output).
I think this may be due to the fact that "distance" is not sorted, and fill_between is using distance[0] and distance[-1] as begin and end for the span, respectively.
As always, any help would be highly appreciated!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        
distance=[0.35645334340084989, 0.55406894241607718, 0.10201413273193734, 0.13401365724625941, 0.71918808865838735, 0.14151335417722818]
time=[2.4004984846346171, 2.4909766335028447, 1.9852064018125195, 1.9083156734132103, 2.6380396934372863, 1.9114505780323543]
time_SD=[0.062393810960652669, 0.056945715242838917, 0.073960838867327183, 0.084111239062664475, 0.026912957190265499, 0.08595664694840538]
distance_SD=[0.035160608598240162, 0.032976715460514235, 0.02782911002465227, 0.035465701695038584, 0.043009444687382707, 0.038387585107200854]
a=1.17887019041
b=1.83339229489
a_sd=0.159771527859
b_sd=0.0762509747218
        
plt.errorbar(distance,time,yerr=time_SD, xerr=distance_SD, linestyle="None") 
abline_values = [(a)*i + (b) for i in distance]
abline_values_plus = [(a+a_sd)*i + (b+b_sd) for i in distance]
abline_values_minus = [(a-a_sd)*i + (b-b_sd) for i in distance]
plt.plot(distance, abline_values,"r")
plt.fill_between(distance,abline_values_minus,abline_values_plus,facecolor='lightgrey', interpolate=True, edgecolors="None")
leg = plt.legend(loc="lower right", frameon=False, handlelength=0, handletextpad=0)
for item in leg.legendHandles:
    item.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `pyplot.fill_between()` **the list to plot the horizontal coordinate should be sorted**. Using an unsorted list of x values is possible, but can lead to undesired results.

Sorting a list can be done using `sorted(list)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

distance=[0.35645334340084989, 0.55406894241607718, 0.10201413273193734, 0.13401365724625941, 0.71918808865838735, 0.14151335417722818]
time=[2.4004984846346171, 2.4909766335028447, 1.9852064018125195, 1.9083156734132103, 2.6380396934372863, 1.9114505780323543]
time_SD=[0.062393810960652669, 0.056945715242838917, 0.073960838867327183, 0.084111239062664475, 0.026912957190265499, 0.08595664694840538]
distance_SD=[0.035160608598240162, 0.032976715460514235, 0.02782911002465227, 0.035465701695038584, 0.043009444687382707, 0.038387585107200854]
a=1.17887019041
b=1.83339229489
a_sd=0.159771527859
b_sd=0.0762509747218

distance_sorted = sorted(distance)

plt.errorbar(distance,time,yerr=time_SD, xerr=distance_SD, linestyle="None") 
abline_values = [(a)*i + (b) for i in distance_sorted]
abline_values_plus = [(a+a_sd)*i + (b+b_sd) for i in distance_sorted]
abline_values_minus = [(a-a_sd)*i + (b-b_sd) for i in distance_sorted]
plt.plot(distance_sorted, abline_values,"r")

plt.fill_between(distance_sorted,abline_values_minus,abline_values_plus, facecolor='lightgrey', edgecolors="None")

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

The documentation does not mention the requirement of x values being sorted. The reason is probably that fill_between actually works even with unsorted lists, just not the way one might expect. Maybe the following animation gives a more intuitive understanding on the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are right `fill_between` seems to expect the values to be sorted. The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between)  is not clear about this behaviour though. The following example however shows the same effect:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import random, array

#x = random.randn(20) #does not work
x = array(sorted(random.randn(20))) #works

a = 2
d = .5

y_h = x*(a+d)
y_l = x*(a-d)

plt.fill_between(x,y_h, y_l)
plt.show()
```

As a workaround just sort your values before calculating your errorlines using `sorted`.

Comment: I think `fill_between` does not expect anything, it's more that people might expect something different, when using it with unsorted lists (see my updated answer). Since it's working with unsorted lists, the documentation does not tell anything about that.